# var/www permissions and FTP

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, lamp

There are many threads about this topic but many are subjective since it's such a flexible subject, so I hope I'm asking an objective question relevant to my setup which is: is this is a sensible approach to the problem of Apache and FTP permissions.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit LAMP server running in Amazon's EC2; Apache2, MySQL, PHP.

Apache2 runs under www-data.

Apache2 default site disabled.
Site:  mysitename.com enabled.

sitesavailable/mysitename.com configured, with DocumentRoot and the Directory directive to point to /mnt/ebs1/public_html

In order to FTP files to the above public_html directory and also be able to manage them from the terminal, I created two specific user accounts and a group:

remote-system-user
remote-ftp-user
group:  ftp

remote-system-user is a member of the admin group so is able to perform sudo operations at the terminal, and also the ftp group.  It was created with 'adduser' and has a home directory.

remote-ftp-user is only a member of the ftp group.  It was created with 'useradd' and does not have a home directory.

I then set permissions on /mnt/eb1/public_html like this:

sudo chgrp -R ftp /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www

I use proFTPd as an FTP server, and using it's conf file, I jail the FTP user to /mnt/ebs1/public_html

Other than perhaps choosing a better name for the ftp group, since it's a bit illogical if the remote SSH user is also a member, what are people's comments on this setup?

The objective is to not give www-data full permissions to the public_html folder, but I will need site users to be able to upload files.  I intend to create a folder within public_html which is writable by www-data to solve that issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved that trouble using same web server user, the trouble is that you wanna access using group privileges, but usually group haven't same user auth, I mean for web server files, when I was on Apache1 (I dunno if that module is available for Apache2) I used to specific the userid and the group owner for each virtualhost, that was usefull to have an ftp user for each virtual server too...